# Get assembly from MVC View in plugin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mef

So I have a MEF plugin for my MVC app.  The controller is in the plugin dll, as to is the view (cshtml) - both are copied to a `plugin` folder and loaded at runtime.

I've written a Url extension helper that will return, from plugin views and content url from a relative url.

What I am trying to get is the assembly of the plugin from the view without passing in a type from the view.

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{        
    public static string PluginContent(this UrlHelper url, string resource)
    {
        var asm = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly();
        // asm == App_Web_ssqr4slf, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null - not my plugin - 
        // is there a way of getting this UrlHelper - obviously getting the controller would do it

    }
}
```

So from my extension method, I am trying to get a reference or type of something in the plugin without having to pass a type or assembly as an argument

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to save it in a ViewBag, that way you don't have to pass a type as the argument.

Comment: I could use a base controller class, is there a way of setting a ViewBag variable for each view?

Comment: and can you get to viewbag from UrlHelper?

Comment: If you want to put all the variables for each view in 1 ViewBag you have to move the data in a variable in your view if you want to use it (what you didn't want to do in the first place). And yes, you can get to ViewBag from UrlHelper.

Comment: Another way of doing it (if you dont have that many views to work with) you can just save a different thing on your ViewBag depending on what view you are in with 'if'. But if you have more Views that would be a pain to do.

Comment: thanks, I simply want to add a variable to the ViewBag for each request, do you know how I could do this? and how can you get the ViewData from UrlHelper?  - thanks in advance

Comment: You can add things to the ViewBag (if thats what you ment) but then you have to go thought it and filter the data it saves.  And I dont think ViewData was made to be used in this sense, you can still try to work around with a ViewBag, but i dont think ViewData can be used as such.